# What can be said about the measurability of $f(x,\cdot):Y\to\mathbb{R}$ if $f:X\times Y\to\mathbb{R}$ is not measurable?

Tags: measurable-functions

Assume that $(X,\Sigma)$ and $(Y,\text{T})$ are measurable spaces and the function $f:X\times Y\to\mathbb{R}$ is not measurable. Can we say anything about the (non) measurability of the function $f(x,\cdot):Y\to\mathbb{R}$ for fixed $x\in X$?

Comment: Take $f(x,y)=g(y)$ where $g$ is not measurable.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy oh thanks! If we exclude this case, can we then say anything about the (non) measurability?

Comment: No. $f(x,.)$ can be measuarble for each $x$ without $f$ being measurable.